Error: Exception in HostObject::get for prop > 'NativeUnimoduleProxy' - Android Virtual Device (AVD) crashes using Expo to test React Native App
Problem
I want to test/emulate a newly created default React Native App.
However, opening an Android Virtual Device (AVD) from the Expo Terminal in Visual Studio Code raises 2 Uncaught Errors:

ERROR  Error: Exception in HostObject::get for prop
'NativeUnimoduleProxy': java.lang.SecurityException: Permission
Denial: registerScreenCaptureObserver from pid=7315, uid=10197
requires android.permission.DETECT_SCREEN_CAPTURE
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered.

How to reproduce the error
I followed the official React Native documentation for the Expo Go Quickstart running the npm commands:
npx create-expo-app AwesomeProject
cd AwesomeProject

which successfully creates a new React Native Project.
To test/emulate the default App.js a server is successfully started in the Visual Studio Code Terminal with the command
npx expo start

Now I start Android Studio and open the Virtual Device Manager. I successfully start the newly created Pixel 7 Device. The AVD opens without issues and shows the device as you would expect.
Back in the Visual Studio Code Terminal I press a to open Android Virtual Device emulation with Expo.
a

The focus automatically switches to the AVD, it even finished "bundling 100%" but then shows 2 Uncaught Errors on the AVD:

and also in the Visual Studio Code Expo Terminal


Use an older Android API Version when creating your Android Virtual Device (AVD).
This error happens only when using an AVD running the latest Android API Versions i.e.:

VanillaIceCream and
UpsideDownCakePrivacySandbox.

After testing extensively it turned out that Android Virtual Devices with API 31 to API 34 and also API TiramisuPrivacySandbox work just fine.
With these API Versions there are no errors and the React Native App is emulated automatically and correctly by simply pressing a in the Visual Studio Code Terminal.
